# Check valid index for 2D array swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array and I'm trying to check if the indexes are valid.

Below is my code and it works as expected.

I'm curious to know if that's right solution? I'm sure there should be pretty neat solution to this rather than what I did. Please advice

```
fileprivate func isValid(index1: Int, index2: Int) -> Bool {
    return myArray?.indices.contains(index1) ?? false && myArray?[index1].indices.contains(index2) ?? false
}
```

Comment: Why don't you write some tests for it, and check in a way that'll not only validate your work today, but also automatically check that it stay correct even after future changes?

Comment: You'd significantly simplify this if you made `myArray` non-optional. Is there an actual difference in your system between "empty array" and "no array?" If not, then just use `[]` instead of nil. And always remember, `[[]]` is not a 2D array. It's an array of arrays. If you want to build a 2D array, then you'll want to build it on top of a simple Array, and use multiplication and addition to access into it.

Comment: Not sure how fast `contains` is in this case but one option would be `index1 >= 0 && index1 < myArray.count` and so on

Comment: @JoakimDanielson contains for an Int range is pretty fast

Comment: @LeoDabus I suspected that :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson even count is O(1) for [RandomAccessCollection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/3017670-count)

Comment: @LeoDabus That shows it can be worth reading the documentation even for a very simple and obvious property, thanks.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `(1...10).contains(5)` will produce precisely the same machine code as `1 <= 5 && 5 <= 10`, without the opportunity to mix up `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `&&` and `||`. I usually suggest people *exclusively* use that for int range checks, for hand rolling the same definition, having it be longer/messier, and often with an off-by-1 error

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I agree that the code gets uglier and more error prone with <=, > etc and I merely suggested it because I wasn't sure how fast `contains` was and even if it wasn't a very useful suggestion it turned into a useful discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in comment by @Rob Napier you should declare your array as non optional and initialize it with an empty collection `[]`. To check if you have valid indices for your collection and sub collection it would be better to extend `Collection` constraining its elements to another `Collection`:

```
extension Collection where Element: Collection {
    func contains(index: Index, subIndex: Element.Index) -> Bool {
       indices.contains(index) && self[index].indices.contains(subIndex)
   }
}
```

---

```
let arrayOfarrays = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]]
arrayOfarrays.contains(index: 2, subIndex: 0)  // true
arrayOfarrays.contains(index: 2, subIndex: 1)  // false
arrayOfarrays.contains(index: 3, subIndex: 0)  // false
```